# Montagem de mapa estilo site bomnegocio.com

Tags: jquery, css

Bom, eu gostaria de saber como que se faz pra criar um mapa estilo o do site `bomnegocio.com`. Eu não sei se naquele mapa existe uma única imagem ou várias imagens agrupadas.

Alguém poderia me da uma luz de como se faz aquele efeito?

Comment: Se está se referindo ao mapa da página inicial, ele é feito com SVG, olhe o código fonte e verá.

Comment: Tem um plugin de edição e criação de SVG, muito bom! http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Criar um mapa interativo SVG é simples porém trabalhoso.

Primeiramente deve-se criar o arquivo SVG, É necessário criar os estado separadamente, para isso vou demonstrar utilizando o editor de imagens **[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)**:

Abra o *GIMP* e importe uma imagem do mapa do Brasil

[image: Mapa Brasil Gimp]

Redimensione a imagem para o tamanho desejado, no exemplo o tamanho é `600px X 590px`.

Selecione o primeiro estado, no exemplo selecionei o Acre, mais é indiferente.

Usando a ferramenta de seleção varinha mágica, selecione o estado.

[image: Selecionando Estado]

Após selecionado, clique no menu **Selecionar > Para vetor**

[image: selecionar para vetor]

Habilite a janela vetores, clicando no menu **Janelas > Diálogos de encaixe > Vetores**. Clique com o botão direito no vetor e exportar para vetor:

[image: exportar para vetor]

Salve e abra o arquivo, usando o [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), você encontrará o código:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="600" height="590"
     viewBox="0 0 432 428">
  <path id="seleçao" ...
```

Altere o `id` do `path` para id desejado do estado, exemplo:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="600" height="590"
     viewBox="0 0 432 428">
  <path id="acre" ...
```

Repita o processo para cada estado, porém nos próximos você somente utilizará o código `path` gerado. Dessa forma será possível gerar o código SVG do desenho e trabalhar com CSS e jQuery e manipular o mapa da forma que desejar.

No exemplo, criei uma `div` com `id="mapa"` e coloquei o código dentro desta `div`:

```
<div id="mapa">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="590" viewBox="0 0 432 428">
    <path id="acre" data-name="Acre"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 40.00,152.22
           C 40.00 ..." />
    <text x="15" y="160">AC</text>

    <path id="amazonas" data-name="Amazonas"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 107.4 ..." />
    <text x="95" y="105">AM</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

No CSS

```
#mapa svg path {
    stroke:#200772; /*cor da borda do estado*/
    fill:#4671D5; /*cor do estado*/
    cursor:pointer;
}

#mapa svg path:hover {
    fill:#be2f33;
    stroke:#be2f33;
}
```

Veja no exemplo simples online, com apenas dois estados **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E573B/4/)**, pois conforme mencionei é trabalhoso :)

**Obs: Este é um exemplo simples de como criar, pode-se trabalhar para adicionar os textos, siglas e o que mais desejar.**

Comment: Depois de tudo pronto, como eu faço para linkar pagina por pagina de cada estado?

Comment: @Lucas você pode colocar a tag `<a xlink:href="..."></a>`, ou pode abrir a página que deseja com jQuery, http://jsfiddle.net/E573B/38/, no exemplo o estado do Acre abre com jQuery e o do Amazonas com tag `<a>`

Comment: Revivendo! é possível realizar o mesmo "serviço" só que com imagens "desenhas" ou seja, imagens que tenha ilustrações reais e não cor solida como o exemplo!

Comment: @abfurlan se eu pudesse votar com up mais de uma vez eu faria! Me ajudou muito!